# UILabel with multiple lines and Auto Resizing Masks (UIViewAutoresizingMask)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, autoresizingmask

I have a problem with `UILabels` that contain text that is spread on multiple lines. It's nested into a fullscreen `UIView` that has `autoresizing` mask as well:

```
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

I'd like to add autoresizingMask on the label

```
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

But the problem is, this doesn't work as I'd like it to work. If I do this, after rotating the screen (which changes size of the view) then the label has smaller height and some of the text is cut off. (It doesn't display the whole text). If I don't add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, then the label after rotation has big gaps above and under text (And I don't want that).

I also tried adding `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`, but this doesn't help, as still not whole text is displayed.

**EDIT:**
I really don't think Autoresizing Masks are going to solve this problem -> autoresizing masks resize view according to changes of size in superview. That's why height won't fit the text. The only solution I could think of is reseting the `UILabel` frame after superview gets resized. If I'm wrong, I'd gladly get corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    self.label.numberOfLines = 10;
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Unfortunatelly this code didn't work for me. Moreover, I don't know how many lines the text will have -> if the device is in portrait orientation, it will be spread into more lines, because lines would be narrower. If the device is in landscape mode, lines are longer, thus requiring less lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use fitToSize(or any of the versions) method on label? Just remember to set number of lines to 0.

```
self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.label fitToSize];
```

EDIT : It is     [self.label sizeToFit];

Comment: No, because I don't have problem on constructing of the UILabel, when it's displayed in original frame, it's ok. The problem arises after rotating screen. But I am almost sure, autoresizing masks can't solve this type of problem and make it worse actually. Probably the only solution would be to override some UILabel method.